# Getting data into an array from a separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

So I have a huge javascript file that is named locationsarray.js. I want to however call this file into this code

```
var myStringArray = ["Hello","World"];

var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  //Do something
}
```

I'm not sure how to get that file into this array. Lastly I need to find a way to output the data within the file into html with `new google.maps.LatLng()` so that it would plot the points on the map. I'm sorry if this is vague but that's as far as my understanding goes. Please help!

The code for the outside javascript file is structured so:

```
 var lsz = 10090;

var CountryTerritory = Array([lsz]);
var Region = Array([lsz]);
var City = Array([lsz]);
var Clicks = Array([lsz]);

CountryTerritory[0] = "United States";
Region[0] = "Florida";
City[0] = "Lauderdale-by-the-Sea";
Clicks[0] = "1";

CountryTerritory[1] = "United States";
Region[1] = "Florida";
City[1] = "Lake Lorraine";
Clicks[1] = "1";

CountryTerritory[2] = "United States";
Region[2] = "Florida";
City[2] = "Palmetto Estates";
Clicks[2] = "1";
```

Comment: How is it structures? Did you try just including both?

Answer (score 0):

In you HTML, include both scripts one after the other, starting with the outer:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./outerScript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./innerScript"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
```

This will make them use the same scope, so if the first script has `var arr = []`

You can use `arr` in the second.

Comment: Ok and how would I call the data in the array to display in HTML with the google maps code?